# Bouncy Castle C#: How do I define a curve and points in order to test/play with EC point arithmetic?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I had a simple EC library for C#, but it is gone and I can't find it on the web.  It was previously published on MSDN, but the [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Elliptic-Curve-Arithmetic-2c433b84/sourcecode?fileId=145524&pathId=1748921262) is now dead.

I am trying to use the Bouncy Castle Library to accomplish similar tasks.  I want to Create a curve (secp256k1), and I want to be able to do point arithmetic and view the raw point data.

i.e.:

G + 3 * G = 4 * G

p + q

4 * G - G = 3 * G

etc.

What namespaces do I need to include, how do I define / declare the curve, and how do I define my points?
I have successfully (I believe...) included the Bouncy Castle .dll in my C# project.

I am NOT interested in creating keys or anything of that sort.  Just EC point arithmetic.  A different (simple) library that would allow me to do the these same operations would be just as good or better.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
I have continued to work on this, and my code looks like this:

```
    private static ECDomainParameters GetCurveParameters(string name)
    {
        X9ECParameters ecP = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName(name);

        if (ecP == null)
            throw new Exception("unknown curve name: " + name);

        return new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N, ecP.H, ecP.GetSeed());
    }

    private void btnTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ECDomainParameters ecSpec = GetCurveParameters("secp256k1");
        ECCurve mycurve = ecSpec.Curve;

        ECPoint G, g2, twoG, threeG;

        G = ecSpec.G;
        g2 = ecSpec.G;

        twoG = G.Add(g2);
        threeG = G.Multiply(new BigInteger("3"));
    }
```

Now, I am able to run the code, and I am getting values back, but I'm not getting the correct points.  G is correct, but all of the others are incorrect.
i.e.:

```
2*G or G+G should =
c6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5,
  1ae168fea63dc339a3c58419466ceaeef7f632653266d0e1236431a950cfe52a

I am getting:
7d152c041ea8e1dc2191843d1fa9db55b68f88fef695e2c791d40444b365afc2,
  56915849f52cc8f76f5fd7e4bf60db4a43bf633e1b1383f85fe89164bfadcbdb
```

G * 3 is also incorrect.

(What I am calling correct is coming from the PyCoin application and can also be verified at [this EC arithmetic website](http://www.christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx).)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use ECPoint.Normalize to return an ECPoint whose (X, Y) coordinates can be compared to PyCoin.

Details: By default (BouncyCastle's) `ECPoint` operations are performed in projective coordinates; specifically what are usually called "Jacobian modified coordinates". This is for performance when performing a series of operations, especially a scalar multiplication. If you print out the value of e.g. `twoG` using the provided `ECPoint.ToString` method, you will see the extra coordinates present.

When you want to compare an `ECPoint` to some (X, Y) value, you can call `ECPoint.Normalize`, which returns a new `ECPoint` where the Z coordinate is 1 and the X and Y coordinates are the affine values. It is a relatively expensive operation that is usually avoided until the final step of a larger calculation.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Syntax is:
twoG.Normalize();